# Prolog - IndexofElement

Tags: list, indexing, prolog, element

I have to find all Indexes of a given Element in a List and return it as a list. So for example:

```
?- indexList(a,[a,b,c,a,b],Rs).
Rs = [0,3]
```

My Idea is:

```
positions( E, L, P ) :- positions( E, L, 0, Rs ).
positions( E, [], _, [] ).
positions( E, [E|Xs], P, [P|PT] ) :- P1 is P + 1, positions( E, Xs, P1, PT ).
positions( E, [X|Xs], P, PT ) :-  P1 is P+1, positions( E, Xs, P1, PT ).
```

When I trace this I get a List in which every Position is in (in the step before the last step). But in the last steps he somehow changes it and returns just true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that instead of using `Rs` to return the list of positions you are using `P`.
You should have seen a lint warning (singleton variables P and Rs) in `positions/3` that should have warned you of this.

Also, in the third clause of `positions/4` you should check that E is different than X:

```
positions( E, L, Rs ) :- positions( E, L, 0, Rs ).
positions( E, [], _, [] ).
positions( E, [E|Xs], P, [P|PT] ) :- P1 is P + 1, positions( E, Xs, P1, PT ).
positions( E, [X|Xs], P, PT ) :-  E\=X, P1 is P+1, positions( E, Xs, P1, PT ).
```

Answer (score 2):

You made a small mistake in the first line. You are invoking `positions(E, L, 0, Rs)`, but the last parameter should be `P`, in order to make a binding with the last parameter with the same name from the head of the clause. So the first line should look like this:

```
positions(E, L, P) :- positions(E, L, 0, P).
```

Comment: gusbro's observation, regarding the checking of E being different than X, is needed only when you ask for more than just the first solution, which will be the correct one in either case. Try to run your code with and without the modification and see what happens.